# xml Append, File.Add... overwrites original data

Tags: xml, linq, append

I'm having issues with xml.linq.
I'm able to create a file and add some details, but when I try to add more information it overwrites the original data.

```
Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter new Customer Id");
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Customers First Name:");
string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Customers Surname:");
string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Contact Telephone Number:");
string phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The First Line of the Delivery Address:");
string firstLineAddress = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Second Line of the Address:");
string secondLineAddress = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Town / City:");
string townCity = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Postcode");
string postCode = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Customers Email Address");
string emailAddress = Console.ReadLine();
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
new XComment("Customer Database"),
new XElement("customer", new XAttribute("CustomerId", id),
                          new XElement("firstName", firstName),
                          new XElement("lastName", lastName),
                          new XElement("firstLineAddress", firstLineAddress),
                          new XElement("secondLineAddress", secondLineAddress),
                          new XElement("cityTown", townCity),
                          new XElement("postCode", postCode),
                          new XElement("phoneNumber", phoneNumber),
                          new XElement("emailAddress", emailAddress)));
doc.Save("CustomerDatabase\\Customer.xml");
```

I understand that why this is happening, I just can't figure out how to file.Append (or something like that.) Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting separate independent Xml documents in the same file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customer>...</customer>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customer>...</customer>
```

Then remove the `doc.Save` line and replace it with `File.AppendAllText("CustomerDatabase\\Customer.xml", doc.ToString());`

Or a single document with many customers, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customers>
  <customer>...</customer>
  <customer>...</customer>
</customers>
```

Then you need to load the original data from disk, add the new element in to the data as you are already doing, then save the whole thing back to disk.

```
var newCustomer = new XElement("customer", new XAttribute("CustomerId", id),
                                  new XElement("firstName", firstName),
                                  new XElement("lastName", lastName),
                                  new XElement("firstLineAddress", firstLineAddress),
                                  new XElement("secondLineAddress", secondLineAddress),
                                  new XElement("cityTown", townCity),
                                  new XElement("postCode", postCode),
                                  new XElement("phoneNumber", phoneNumber),
                                  new XElement("emailAddress", emailAddress)));

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("CustomerDatabase\\Customer.xml");
var customers= doc.Element("customers");
customers.Add(newCustomer);
doc.Save("CustomerDatabase\\Customer.xml");
```

Both of these approaches come with pros and cons:
The first is most likely not what you are after, this is generally not how you would store xml data. The second is better but it is disk heavy when the document gets larger. The preferred option in this case would be to store a single XDocument in memory and add to it then save to disk rather than read and write each time.

Comment: Thank you, its been driving me crazy. as I'm sure you may have guessed I'm still very new to this. I will definitely take a look at storing XDocuments to memory also..  Cheers